# What are the advantages of a random effects model versus a pooled OLS regression with cluster–robust standard errors?

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, pooling

Both models allow for explanatory variables that are time-invariant.

I had thought that the advantage of a random effects model might be related to the fact that random effects models mitigate serial correlation (does it?) whereas pooled OLS regression with cluster–robust standard errors do not, but I then found a [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86807/clustered-standard-errors-and-pooled-ols) that noted (emphasis added):

> **Clustered standard errors** are robust to heteroskedasticity and **serial correlation in the error term**. In that sense, clustered standard errors are "appropriate" when you think this is the case in
>   your context, as they still give you valid inference. One likely
>   reason in panel data for (positive) serial correlation in the error
>   term is the presence of time-invariant unobservables. However, if
>   there are such time-invariant unobservables, other estimators might be
>   more appropriate than pooled OLS, e.g. fixed effects if you think the
>   time-invariant unobservables are correlated with your regressors, or
>   random effects if you think there is no such correlation.

A related question is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103813/using-pooled-ols-when-running-a-model-with-panel-data) but the person who asked that question asked about pooled OLS (not pooled OLS regression with cluster–robust standard errors).

Comment: Related questions: 1. Does the pooled OLS with cluster-robust standard errors automatically handle heteroskedasticity? 2. What about RE models and heteroskedasticity? 3. Does pooled OLS with cluster-robust standard errors automatically manage autocorrelation? 4. Do RE models manage autocorrelation? Or does autocorrelation mean one must build extra bells and whistles (like Arellano-Bond estimators?) into the model?